# Restrict access in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server. I have a view (`VIEW1`) in `DB1`.

Now, I have created another (`VIEW2`) in `DB2`:

```
Create VIEW2 as Select * from DB1.VIEW1 where id not in (select ID from DB2.Table2)
```

I want a user to be able to select from `DB2.VIEW2`, but not from `DB1.VIEW1` directly.

In other words, this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM DB2.VIEW2
```

and this would not:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.VIEW1
```

Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `view2` selects from `view1` **in another database**, as it configured now the permissions on view1 will be checked, so if you just do

```
DENY SELECT ON [dbo].[ViewName] TO [UserWithoutAccess]
```

your select from view2 will fail with

> The SELECT permission was denied on view1, schema dbo, database db1.

What you should do is to enable your databases to cross-db chaining:
[Enabling Cross-Database Access in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server)

i.e. execute this in both databases:

```
ALTER DATABASE db1 SET DB_CHAINING ON;  
ALTER DATABASE db2 SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

This way ownership chain will not be broken when you pass to another database and the permissions on `view1` will not be checked.

Database owners of db1, db2 should be the same.

More on ownership chaining here: [Ownership Chains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx)